# Does `context.contentResolver.query()` run on UI thread?

Tags: android

I am working on a application to get call logs, I am finding it hard to find if context.contentResolver.query() runs on UI thread and if I have to move it to background thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, Yes you can call query() in  ui thread. However, it is not recommeded for performace perspective.

query() has high cost, it's better to call in worker thread.

You can implement async query easily by using Loaders.